# React, Redux: Uncaught ReferenceError: posts is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

Basically I have an import statement that takes in some JSON data held on a file, which I am now reading in from firebase, and am attempting to pass the value of the returned data into defaultstate{}, but am receiving the above mentioned error message. How do I resolve this?:

```
store.js

import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

// import the root reducer
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';

//Firebase configuration details and initialisation
import { Firebase_Config } from '../config/config';
firebase.initializeApp(Firebase_Config);
const rootRef = firebase.database();
const refPosts = rootRef.ref('posts');

refPosts.on("value", snapshot => {
  const posts = snapshot.val(); // I wish to pass this into defaultState{}
}, errorObject => {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});

// Get initial state of all comments and posts
import comments from '../config/comments';
// import posts from '../config/posts';

// create an object for the default data
const defaultState = {
  posts : posts, // I wish to pass in the snapshot value here
  comments
};
```

Comment: Presumably `refPosts.on` happens asynchronously right? If that's the case then posts will not exist by the time your defaultState is created. What if you instead create an empty array as your default state, then dispatch an action to add posts when your snapshot returns?

Comment: @azium the `value` event from Firebase indeed fires asynchronously. Can you write your comment into an answer?